# Is there a way to load data from only one column in an excel sheet to an existinng mysql table?

Tags: mysql, excel

I know it is possible using LOAD keyword to import a whole table in excel into mysql, e.g.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/path/to/boats.csv" INTO TABLE boatdb.boats
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, name, type, owner_id, @datevar, rental_price)
set date_made = STR_TO_DATE(@datevar,'%m/%d/%Y');
```

According to the example given in : https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/excel-to-mysql/ but what for a single column ?

Comment: 'You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable and not assigning the variable to a table column:' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: In this way, a completely new set of rows appears with values corresponding to the other column are NULL. When trying to add a new column it is appearing with NULL values.